# Consider functions $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \to \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$. How many functions have the property that $f(1) \not= c$ or $f(2) \not= f$, or both?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider functions $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \to \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$. How many functions have the property that $f(1) \not= c$ or $f(2) \not= f$, or both?

I tried $6^6-6^2=45360$, but this is not the right answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Think carefully about why you're subtracting $6^2$.

Comment: Isn't it because there are two functions, f(1)≠c or f(2)≠f that we do not want as an outcome?

Comment: Let me ask you a simpler question: how many functions you have that have $f(1)=c$?

Comment: That would be 36? C(6,1)*C(6,1)

Answer (score 3):

It helps to think using set properties.

Let $A$ be the set of all functions for which $f(1)=c$ and $B$ denote the set of all functions for which $f(2)=f$.

Then functions having the property that $f(1)\neq c$ or $f(2)\neq f$ or both, belong to $\bar{A} \cup \bar{B}$. We know $$\bar{A} \cup \bar{B} = \overline{A \cap B}$$

Since $|A \cap B|=1\cdot 1 \cdot 6^4$, required answer is
$$|\overline{A \cap B}|=6^6-6^4=45360$$

Comment: Why $4^6$? I can have six values for each of the $3,4,5,6$, so that would be $6^4$

Comment: @Andrei Oversight. Corrected, thanks!